# get child pages of parent ID and display custom image field with link to page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to get list of child pages, but i need to exclude the first child. I also need to display a custom image field called'page_icon' with url and page title for each. This will act as a sub menu whic will be displayed on each child page. Each menu item needs to have the current class attached to the a tag. i've tried a number of different methods and have had no luck as my skill level is beginner at best.

the parent ID is 1064
the custom field is called 'page_icon' which was set up using ACF

the current menu is hard coded into the editor and the html looks like this: -

```
<div id="attachment_1306" style="width: 160px" class="wp-caption alignleft"><a class="icon on" href="http://www.domain.co.uk/category/category/category/"><img class="wp-image-1306 size-thumbnail" title="Policy Manager" src="http://www.domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/docs-150x150.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" /></a><p class="wp-caption-text">Policy Manager</p></div>

 <div id="attachment_1297" style="width: 160px" class="wp-caption alignleft"><a class="icon" href="http://www.domain.co.uk/category/category/category/"><img class="wp-image-1297 size-thumbnail" title="Risk Manager" src="http://www.domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/risk-150x150.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" /></a><p class="wp-caption-text">Risk Manager</p></div>

 <div id="attachment_1307" style="width: 160px" class="wp-caption alignleft"><a class="icon" title="Controls Manager" href="http://www.domain.co.uk/governance-risk-and-category/category/category/"><img class="wp-image-1307 size-thumbnail" title="Controls Manager" src="http://www.domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/controls-150x150.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" /></a><p class="wp-caption-text">Controls Manager</p></div>

 <div id="attachment_1301" style="width: 160px" class="wp-caption alignleft"><a class="icon" title="Incident Manager" href="http://www.domain.co.uk/category/category/category/"><img class="wp-image-1301 size-thumbnail" title="Incident Manager" src="http://www.domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/incident-150x150.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" /></a><p class="wp-caption-text">Incident Manager</p></div>

 <div id="attachment_1289" style="width: 160px" class="wp-caption alignleft"><a class="icon" title="Workflow Manager" href="http://www.domain.co.uk/category/category/category/"><img class="wp-image-1289 size-thumbnail" title="Workflow Manager" src="http://www.corestream.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/workflow-150x150.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" /></a><p class="wp-caption-text">Workflow Manager</p></div>
```

but this is not user friendly in terms of updating the page icons as you have to copy and paste this into each child page.

please someone help me?

Comment: Just to clarify; is the menu supposed to contain the same information (a list of Page 1064s child pages, minus the first child) on every page?

Comment: yes, so minus the first child which is an overview page (which will also contain the sub menu), every child page will display the subimenu as icons above the main content. here is a static example http://www.corestream.co.uk/governance-risk-and-compliance/solutions/integrated-grc/

Comment: Ok, I think I sort of understand. One more thing; the text strings ("Workflow Manager", etc) - are they they set as post title of the corresponding page?

Comment: yes they are the page titles. these are all set up as pages not posts just to clarify, not sure if it makes any difference. as you can see in the html the icons have captions below each icon which are the page titles.

Comment: also the order of the buttons should be as per their position in the page order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a file called solutions_menu.php in your theme's directory (/wp-content/themes/your-theme/solutions_menu.php). This file will contain the menu, and will be included in to your pages.

#### Edit:

I replaced the for-loop with a foreach-loop. Then I added another ACF field for when post type == page to control whether to show the page in the menu or not. It's a simple boolean (true/false) field with the name "appear_in_solutions_menu". I'm not sure this is the best way to solve it but it's working at least.

Here's a working example using the code below: http://japmag.net/24909031/?page_id=6

### solutions_menu.php

```
<?php

# Parent ID
$parent_id = 1064;

# Arguments for the query
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $parent_id,
    'post_type'   => 'page', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish' 
    ); 

# The parent's children
$kids = get_children( $args );

# Current pages ID
$page_ID = get_the_ID();

# Start iterating from 1, to skip first child
foreach( $kids as $kid ) {
    
    # Set variables
    $id = $kid->ID;
    $url = get_permalink( $id );
    $page_icon_array = get_field( 'page_icon', $id );
    $page_icon = $page_icon_array[ 'url' ];
    $title = $kid->post_title;
    $show = get_field( 'appear_in_solutions_menu' , $id );
    
    # Make sure the page shoul be in the menu
    if( $show ) {

        # If the current page ID matches the ID of the child, then $current will contain " on", which will be used to apply the class "on" to the anchor-element
        $current = ( $page_ID == $id ) ? " on" : "";
        
        # Echo out the menu ?>

        <div style="width: 160px" class="wp-caption alignleft">

            <a class="icon<?php echo $current?>" href="<?php echo $url?>">

                <img class="size-thumbnail" title="<?php echo $title ?>" src="<?php echo $page_icon; ?>" alt="" width="150" height="150" />

            </a>

            <p class="wp-caption-text"><?php echo $title ?></p>

        </div>

    <?php 
    
    }

}

?>
```

Now replace the hard-coded menu in your different page files with

```
<?php get_template_part( 'solutions_menu' ); ?>
```

This will include the menu in to your pages, and should hopefully dynamically populate itself with the correct data. So if you need to make changes to the menu, just change solutions_menu.php and all the pages that include it will be affected. I hope I understood the problem correctly. I'm at work right now so I haven't been able to test the code yet.

Comment: thanks Janne, i've added the code but it doesn't work i'm afraid. Here is the output... http://www.corestream.co.uk/?page_id=1423&preview=true

the code has created 7 child page links when there should be 5 and each link has the same link to the page it is on i.e. current page. Also none of the icons or captions are displaying.

Comment: also it maybe an idea to add a filter to display published pages only as some will be created as drafts until ready to be published.

Comment: I'm only seeing a 404-style page when following your link. If the code created 7 child page links, then it's because the parent page (with ID 1064) has 8 child pages. It can be limited in the for loop by replacing "count( $kids )" with [the amount of pages you wish to retrieve +1]. I updated the code to only take published pages into consideration. I get off work in a couple of minutes, I'll help you more when I get home :)

Comment: ok thanks janne, really appreciated. i've published the page but hidden it from any menu's for you to see http://www.corestream.co.uk/policy-manager-test/

i've placed the page out side of the parent so that it isn't picked up in this test. the 6th page that is being picked is a draft which needs to be hidden.

Comment: Don't worry about it @Amesey, I'm learning by helping! :) I updated the answer with a working example. I hope this works for you aswell, or at least points you in the right direction. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Janne appreciate your help. The icons aren't displaying at all now http://www.corestream.co.uk/policy-manager-test/

Comment: Did you create the ACF field 'appear_in_solutions_menu'? And set it to true for all the pages you wish to show in the menu?

Comment: Hi Janne, i just realised that i didn't do that before i saw your last comment. i've now added the field and it displays all the icons http://www.corestream.co.uk/policy-manager-test/

...but now need to get them to display in the order they are in the page order.

everything else works perfectly, thank you very much. If you need a favour let me know :)

Comment: i've added this to the array but it doesn't sort it...

    'sort_column'  => 'menu_order',

Comment: Haha, don't worry about it I'm just glad I can help :) Try using 'orderby' instead of 'sort_column', like this: 'orderby' => 'menu_order'

Comment: Also do note that the menu order refers to the Order specified in the Page Attributes meta box when editing a Page, not to the order you've sorted a custom menu into

Comment: OK thanks Janne :) i've sorted as you advised using 'orderby' => 'menu_order' but its displayed it from last to first, how do i reverse the order? i've tried 'sort_order'   => 'DESC' and 'sort_order'   => 'ASC', but no change

Comment: We're getting close! :) Rather than 'sort_order' try simply using 'order', like this: 'order' => 'ASC'

Comment: Awesome! :) it works perfectly http://www.corestream.co.uk/governance-risk-and-compliance/solutions/integrated-grc/

forver grateful Janne!

Comment: Hooray! We did it finally ;)