# Get the child pages id wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am very new to wordpress and php so excuse me in advance if maybe the answer were already posted, but I looked everwhere and couldnt find a solution to my problem. Or at least I never was able to make work any ideas I tried, and the wordpress documentation is still very complicate for me, when I look through the functions and hook to understand how it is working.
I basically made a slideshow on my home page which display the feature images of the children pages. I have the thumbnails of the images in my side navigation, and the slideshow in my main content section. Basically I am retrieving the ID of each child page by entering the specific id for each slide, but I'd like to make all this dynamic and loop the whole thing, but I don't manage to output the children pages ID dynamically. Here is the hard code I am using now :

```
<div id="contentContainer">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="itemOne" class="content">
    <?php 
     $image_id=get_post_thumbnail_id(192);
     $image_url=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'full-size');
     echo '<img src="'.$image_url[0].'">';
    ?>

    </div>

    <div id="itemTwo" class="content">
    <?php 
        $image_id=get_post_thumbnail_id(196);
        $image_url=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'full-size');
        echo '<img src="'.$image_url[0].'">';

        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="itemThree" class="content">
    <?php
        $image_id=get_post_thumbnail_id(198);
        $image_url=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'full-size');
        echo '<img src="'.$image_url[0].'">';

        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="itemFour" class="content">
    <?php
        $image_id=get_post_thumbnail_id(200);
        $image_url=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'full-size');
        echo '<img src="'.$image_url[0].'">';

        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

As I will have more slides than this later on, and in case I need to change the images without going through code, I would like to get this code dynamic, and looping as much slides as it can be.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get child pages of parent ID and display custom image field with link to page in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909031/get-child-pages-of-parent-id-and-display-custom-image-field-with-link-to-page-in)

Answer (score 0):

You can get page id of children by using

> get_page_children()

here is an example :-

```
    <?php

    // Set up the objects needed
    $my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type'=>'page','posts_per_page' => '-1'));

    // Get the page as an Object
    $parent_page =  get_page_by_title('parent_page_title');

    // Filter through all pages and find page's children
    $page_children = get_page_children( $parent_page->ID, $all_wp_pages );

    // echo children page id from $page_children array
    foreach($page_children as $children):
     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($children->ID);
     echo '</pre>';
    endforeach;
   ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So now it's displaying a list of the ID of my children pages. I put this code into a custom function i called get_children_ID(); . Now how can I select only a specific ID of that array? Like for example I just want the ID of the first child page for the first slide, and Im gonna need the second ID for the second slide and so on. Thank you so much and sorry for been such a newbie, it is still all very vague and I am not sure of what I need to look for.

Comment: you have to modify the code for that, but instead you can put your slider code into foreach loop of this code so you can get images directly as you are getting id of children pages in array.. or you can get specific id by using array index on $page_children array. but if you need more help on that you need to show what you have done and where are you facing the problem.. if this answer solved your query of getting children page id then please accept it and start new question or edit this question with your latest code..